# IntelliJ IDEA UML shortcut

Tags: intellij-idea, uml

According to [this page](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/features/uml_class_diagram.html) I can get UML model using "CTRL+ALT+U" shortcut.
But I cannot make it work in my instance of IDEA, Community Edition version 13.1.3

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Possible steps:

1) Right click on a package from the project panel
2) Near the bottom of the popup, select "Diagrams" then "Show Diagram"
3) Hopefully you will see a class model of the package.

Comment: I don't see "Diagrams" in context menu. Maybe it's because I am using Community Edition. Can you post a screen-shot or other steps?

Comment: I just looked at the IJ feature matrix and you are correct, UML is not supported on the community edition.

Comment: Can you please post the link to the matrix. I did not find any suggestion UML was not supported in community edition in the article I reference in the question.

Comment: Here is a [URL](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/features/) You should see that UML "greys out" when the community edition is selected.

Answer (score 1):

Diagrams are not available in the Community Edition.
[Community vs Ultimate editions comparison.](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/features/editions_comparison_matrix.html)