# IntelliJ Idea UML Designing with Visual Paradigm :Community Edition

Tags: intellij-idea

First: this is not a duplicate. Similar Question can be found 
[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24001429/intellij-idea-uml-shortcut) for IJ 13.

IntelliJ Idea 15 community Edition has a Visual Paradigm Community Edition plugin  [downloadable from here](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/245?pr=idea) and after the installation, any option to draw diagrams is not visible. Any one has tried this ?

Answer (score 1):

According to the last comment on your link:

> You need to install Visual Paradigm as a separate application, this
>   plugin will enable its integration within your IntelliJ.
>   https://www.visual-paradigm.com/download/

Unfortunately visual paradigm is trialware.